# SQL server handling of nvarchar(3) valued '06' as '6'?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that is declared as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddPartsWork]
@Partition_NUM nvarchar(3),
@AptNo INT,
@ExperimentID INT,
@PartID INT,
@SimTime INT,
@Built BIT, 
@Duration INT = NULL
AS ...
```

When I call it from my script, javaScript,  I can trace that the sql statement is in fact

```
EXEC dbo.AddPartsWork 06,4,1,8,118,1,22
```

But, when I PRINT the value of `@Partition_NUM`, I get `6`, instead of `06`.
Is this supposed to happen? 
How do I solve, or handle it in the stored procedure's code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
EXEC dbo.AddPartsWork '06',4,1,8,118,1,22
```